# VS docker-compose project in subdirectory

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose

I use Visual Studio 2019 and have a asp.net core project (.csproj) and a docker-compose project (.dcproj). The file structure is like this:

```
Solution.sln
 - src
   - Project
     - Project.csproj
     - Dockerfile
 - docker-compose.dcproj
 - docker-compose.yml
 - .dockerignore
```

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  project:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}project
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Project/Dockerfile
```

This setup works fine, but I would like to place the docker files in the solution and the file system in a subdirectory, like this:

```
Solution.sln
 - src
   - Project
     - Project.csproj
     - Dockerfile
 > docker
   - docker-compose.dcproj
   - docker-compose.yml
   - .dockerignore
```

I have not been able to get it to work. In the `docker-compose.yml` I tried different approaches for relative paths, but only the absolute path to the solution as the context worked (context: C:\Files\Sources).

Is it possible to get it to work with relative paths?

Comment: valid question.

Comment: @nerdalert yes, and I added an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The final `docker-compose.yml` looks like this in the sample above:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  project:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}project
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./src/Project/Dockerfile
```

I used `../` fot the context to set the root to the solution file level and `./` at the beginning of the dockerfile to start from the context root.